# How to find middle element of doubly linked list using head and tail?

Tags: data-structures, linked-lists

Is there a way possible to find the middle element of a doubly linked list using head and tail. I tried traversing to the next element from the starting node and the previous element from the end node and check if the reference of both is same or not. This works fine if there are odd number of elements in the list. I am not able to find when should I stop in case the number of elements in the list is even.

```
while(head.next != end.previous) {
    head = head.next;
    end = end.previous;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean to find the middle element "in $n/2$"? What are you counting here?

Comment: I meant n/2 iterations.

Comment: What does "iteration" constitute? Otherwise it's hard to argue one way or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a pointer $x$ at the beginning and a pointer $y$ at the end. Repeatedly execute the following steps:

- If $x=y$, stop.
- Advance $x$ forward.
- If $x=y$, stop.
- Advance $y$ backward.

This should work out for both even and odd length.

Comment: But we cannot avoid two comparisons?

Comment: You don't need comparisons at all. You can calculate the length of the list, and then go straight to the middle element.

Comment: Yes, I can. There are other ways too like using 2 pointers. One which points next->next and one which points next. When the first pointer reaches the end, the second will be at mid. I was just curious if we can do it with the way I am working.